# Node.js: What to store in the database during Twitter OAuth?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, twitter, oauth, passport.js

I want to make an absolutely simple Twitter stream, using Express, Passport and socket.io, storing some credentials in a database for easy later retrieval. The problem is, I don't know what to store in the database. Do I store the Tokens that I get in the OAuth callback from Passport?

I also don't know how to make the site 'remember' that the user has authorized before. Do I use Sessions, and if so, how?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This isn't really a question, I'm afraid. Try a node.js or web-developer forum for more general discussion. There might even be a tutorial online for exactly this application.

Comment: @RichardHuxton could you maybe recommend a forum where I can ask the question? I can't seem to find any

Comment: irc, reddit, google groups etc. are all good places to start. Any general web-developer community should do you.